# Noob using C# classes and accessing them

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I'm working with JSON (using json.net) and a C# console application and I am trying to set some values for a JSON POST to a server.

I can set some of the values, but accessing others is giving me fits.

My JSON looks like this:

```
{
    "params" : [
         {
             "url" : "sys/login/user",
             "data" : [
                 {
                     "passwd" : "pwd",
                     "user" : "user"
                 }
             ]
         }
    ],
    "session" : 1,
    "id" : 1,
    "method" : "exec"
}
```

I ran that through json2csharp and it generated me the following classes.

```
public class Datum
{
    public string passwd { get; set; }
    public string user { get; set; }
}

public class Param
{
    public string url { get; set; }
    public List<Datum> data { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Param> @params { get; set; }
    public string session { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string method { get; set; }
}
```

I then created this object for testing in my `Main` method

```
RootObject temp = new RootObject()
temp.id = 1;
temp.method = "exec";
temp.session = "1";
```

and those parameters get set just fine.
I can also set the URL param using the following:

```
temp.@params.Add(new Param { url = "some/url", });
```

It is setting the `public List<Datum> data { get; set; }` item that is the problem.  I cannot figure out how to access that and set the user and password items.

If I add this to the `Param` class I can set the values, but this seems to be the wrong way/place to me.

```
public Param()
{
   data = new List<Datum>();            
   data.Add(new Datum { user = "user", passwd = "pass" });
}
```

Comment: Your question title should be a description of the *problem*, not of (what you think applies to) yourself.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Seeing as this is your first question, I suggest reading [ask] for information on the best way to ask questions here. Your question is pretty good for a newcomer, but it could use some improvement. For instance, the title is very vague and contains little useful info.

Comment: As a start, I'd at least change the property `@params` to something else. json2csharp has put `@` at the beginning of the name because `params` is a C# keyword - see the [C# language spec 2.4.2: Identifiers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664670).

Comment: Please specify why "this seems to be the wrong way/place" to you. Is there anything in particular that does not work when you do it this way? Without knowing that, it will be difficult to suggest an alternative that does not have the same problem.

Comment: @WaiHaLee: As it works like this (that is exactly why the `@` syntax element was introduced to C#) and, seeing the JSON connection, this might be dealing with some reflection-based serialization/deserialization, that suggestion is most likely to break something rather than reduce the amount of trouble.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper you're right - I should have thought about that since my in my comment I clearly acknowledged the JSON connection.

Comment: @O. R. Mapper  It seemed when i set the uname and password in the class itself that those values were 'permanent'.  If i send a second json query to the server, those values are passed even though they are not nedded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you create your `RootObject` like this:

```
RootObject temp = new RootObject()
temp.id = 1;
temp.method = "exec";
temp.session = "1";
```

Then you create the `params` list and fill it with one `Param`:

```
temp.@params = new List<Param>();
temp.@params.Add(new Param { url = "some/url" });
```

You can then set the data for one param in the list (in this example the first one):

```
temp.@params[0].data = new List<Datum>();
temp.@params[0].data.Add(new Datum { user = "user", passwd = "pass" });
```

This is necessary, because  `@params` is a list of `Param` objects. You could also fill the data when creating the `Param` instance before adding it to the list (easier, because you otherwise need to know the list index).

```
temp.@params = new List<Param>();

Param p = new Param { url = "some/url" };
p.data = new List<Datum>();
p.data.Add(new Datum() { ... });

temp.@params.Add(p);
```

Usually you'd change change the default constructors to initialize the lists already and prevent the list instances from being replaced by changing the properties to read-only, but that might not work well with JSON deserialization, so you really need to try this. It would look like this:

```
public class Param
{
    public Param()
    {
        data = new List<Datum>();
    }

    public string url { get; set; }
    public List<Datum> data { get; private set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public RootObject()
    {
        @params = new List<Param>();
    }

    public List<Param> @params { get; private set; }
    public string session { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string method { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You should supply the read-only properties with private setters, or this will yield [CS0840](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397743.aspx).

Comment: Thank you very much!  That is just what i needed to move forward.   Thanks also for the tip on private setters,